# Show on-screen soft button on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

How do I adjust the graphical layout of xml files on Eclipse to get it to show this? Also, what's the official name of this?)

[image]

Comment: In your xml change the dervice to galaxy nexus and you will see them. That's what you mean?

Comment: that is usually referred to as either the navigation bar or on screen navigation (depending on the context).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name for this is the `System Bar` aka `Navigation Bar` aka `On Screen Buttons` aka `Software Buttons`.

As for showing them in the graphical editor, simply select either `Galaxy Nexus`, `Nexus 7`, `10." WXGA` or `7.0" WSVGA` from the screensize dropdown menu in the `Graphical Layout` tab of the layout XML editor.

[image]